# Change zoom factor of QGIS programmatically with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, zoom, mouse-wheel

I would like to change the zoom factor of QGIS dynamically without restarting QGIS.
The changed settings I would like to use for a plugin would be that it let's me dynamically change the zoom behaviour when I **use the mouse wheel for zooming** in and out.

I know that I can change the QGIS-Settings like that:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings
s = QSettings() #getting qgis settings
s.setValue("/Qgis/zoom_factor", 1.1)
s.sync()
```

But this requires a restart of QGIS to really change the zoom behaviour.
Is there anything else I could do to make QGIS accept the new settings like it does when I click the "OK"-button in the settings dialog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to alter settings, you can change the zoom factor for the current QGIS session.

For QGIS <= v2.18 (see [Wheel actions enum](http://www.qgis.org/api/2.14/classQgsMapCanvas.html#afe038b642bd804e350979c7e201a056b)):

```
zoomFactor = 3
iface.mapCanvas().setWheelAction( 0, zoomFactor ) # Wheel action, Zoom factor
```

For upcoming QGIS 3, there is a new method (wheel actions have been removed):

```
zoomFactor = 3
iface.mapCanvas().setWheelFactor( zoomFactor )
```

Comment: Or use [`QgsMapCanvas.WheelZoom`](http://qgis.org/api/2.14/classQgsMapCanvas.html#afe038b642bd804e350979c7e201a056b) instead of `0` to make it a bit better readable. Karma points for mentioning the QGIS 3.0 API.

Comment: This can be also used to switch mouse wheel behavior to "ArcMap" style by setting zoomFactor to below 1, for example: iface.mapCanvas().setWheelFactor( 0.5 )

Comment: Also be aware iface.mapCanvas().setWheelFactor() changes all zoom in / zoom out functionality (tools), not only mouse wheel behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for zoom functions, they are defined in the [QgsMapCanvas Class](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html). For example, in your case it could be used something like this:

```
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
canvas.zoomByFactor(1.1)
```

If I run this code from the Python Console, it zooms the canvas by a factor of 1.1. Does it work for you?

Comment: thanks but I still want use the mouse wheel for zooming. I just want to dynamically adjust how much it zooms in or out when I use the mousewheel

Comment: Sorry, I was distracted. I'm glad you solved your problem.